# Wordpress Custom Hooks For Theme Issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm very new to wordpress. I'm developing a wordpress theme and using social share button plugin to share the post on social networking websites. Now all the social buttons are shown just below the post content. but I want them to show on a custom position in the post div.

the plugin button are shown using the following piece of code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ssb_display');
```

This code shows the social share buttons below post contents but I want them to show on another position in the same post div. How can I do this. Please don't give negative to my question as I'm newbie in wordpress.

Actually i want to define my own filter hook in wordpress then add_filter to that hook.

thanks.

Comment: CSS? Sounds like ssb_display is appending the social stuff to the_content. You can look in teh plugin source and make your own copy of it (my_ssb_display) in your functions.php file and change the way it appends the goods to the content. But really, just try CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of `add_filter` is [`remove_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter), and since the callback is registered by a name function you only need to add

```
// functions.php
remove_filter('the_content', 'ssb_display');
```

And then display, the button where you want.

**Update**

If for any reason you can't use  `ssb_display` function directly in your template, you can use a custom filter with  `apply_filters`

```
// functions.php
add_filter('show_the_ssb_button', 'ssb_display')

// template.php
<?php echo apply_filters('show_the_ssb_button', $content) ?>
```

If `ssb_display` doesn't use specific info from content, then `$content` variable can be an empty string.

Comment: actually I want to create a new filter like show_the_ssb_button and use the line add_filter('show_the_ssb_button', 'ssb_display'); in plugin and use this filter in any position of my theme

Answer (score 0):

Once, you can remove action with this code:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'ssb_display');
```

**Now**, plugin don't add any code your output. And you can add social buttons to where you want with this code:

```
if (function_exists('ssb_share_icons')) 
     echo ssb_share_icons();
```